# Ouputting (clickable) hyperlinks to a spreadsheet with Python pandas.to_excel()

Tags: python, html, pandas

I have a dataframe in which one column is all hyperlinks (eg, http://example.com). I have managed to make these links render as html inside Jupyter Notebook:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
df["URL"] = df["URL"].apply(lambda x: '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(x,x))
df = HTML(df.to_html(escape=False))
df
```

But I cannot get these links written to an Excel (or ODS) spreadsheet as html rather than text. In the above, `df` become a `IPython.core.display.HTML` object, without pandas's `to_excel()`.

When I convert the individual cells to `IPython.core.display.HTML` with `lambda x: HTML('<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(x,x))` and then call `to_excel` on the DataFrame, I get the Exception:

`Unexpected data type <class 'IPython.core.display.HTML'>`

Answer (score 3):

You could use the HYPERLINK function built into pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'link':['=HYPERLINK("http://www.someurl.com", "some website")']})
df.to_excel('mohammad-rocks.xlsx')
```

Comment: Tried that. It's rendering the cell as a `0`. When I click on it, I get ""0" is not an absolute URL that can be passed to an external application to open it." If I copy `'=HYPERLINK("http://www.someurl.com", "some website")'` into a cell inside Excel, then it works.

Comment: @zadrozny just went through the trouble of installing pandas to see what was wrong, the code above works fine for me, here is an image for proof https://imgur.com/a/Afs9X

Comment: It might be an issue with LibreCalc. When I use `to_csv`, then change the file extension to xlsx, the text displays and the link works. Strange.

Comment: @zadrozny maybe try updating python/panda?

Comment: what if the URL (ie, someurl.com) is coming from a variable ?

Comment: @zadrozny Did you find solution to that "0" problem. I am also getting the same.

Comment: @NoHolidays One can obtain the link in an Excel file if the URL comes from a variable as follows: ```'=HYPERLINK("' + link + '", "report")'```